# Mouse interaction with menu separator

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Which event will be raised while scrolling mouse over menu separator?
How to identify separator position in the menu?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more precise.
Could you please explain what do you mean by:
*How to identify separator position in the menu?*

If your application is MFC, there are no events raised.
MFC wraps windows’ API. Windows is a message driven system, not event driven, hence window is receiving messages about mouse movement. 
Menu separator is not a menu item, so you will not receive any message when separator is clicked.

Comment: Clearly i will explain, Previously i was asked a question about Windows CE start menu found at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240325/windows-ce-6-0-r3-start-menu-banner[link]. I have solved that issue by redrawing bitmap using BitBlt function. but i can't be able to redraw while scrolling over Menu separator. that's why i asked the above question.